# =SUMIF Google Spreadsheet Help needed

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to spreadsheets and I need some help.

I created a sheet to register money to be reimbursed.

What I want to do is:

a) The total shows the total amount in Column 'C' but it will subtract the row value only if/when Column 'E' says yes.

b) The total should be on display all time in the merged cells on 'F'.

I was using this:

```
=SUMIF(E2:E9; "Yes"; B2:B9)
```

But I think am Way off.

Any kind of help is welcome.

Spreadsheet for reference: [Link here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tcUlL4Yg_p7o-1t1tv_N592Q9W2k3C2BoB7frXC_jkU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=SUMIF(E:E;"No";C:C)`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much.